# Opacity of the div affects the innerHTML values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with background color as green and opacity as 0.4.

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:green;opacity:0.4">Text</div>
```

And I have a text inside the div. When i set the opacity for the div, the innerHTML values is also affected. I want the div background color with opacity 0.4,and the text with normal opacity. Is it possible to achieve my requirement?

[image: Div with text]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put your text inside <p></p>

Comment: @AbdulMuheet Even if s/he could, it wouldn't help to keep the text from being affected by `opacity`.

Comment: you can wrap your text inside tag p or span and then add your styles to this tag or another solution is use css pseudo class :not, but you will need to put your styles in style tag or another css file

Answer (score 1):

[Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors_legal.asp)

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:rgba(0,200,0,0.4);">Text</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79p33dwq/)

Comment: this is a duplicated solution